# How to save SpeechSynthesisStream as audio in local storage of Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1

I am using a `SpeechSynthesizer` class in my Windows Phone 8.1 Store app (XAML app/ windows runtime app/ universal app). It outputs a SpeechSynthesisStream which i need to save as a mp3/audio file in phone's local storage. Here's the code that i am using to generate the stream. How to save it as an audio file?

```
using (var speech = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
      var voiceStream = await speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't see you there on twitter. Kindly pardon me for that. I think the first thing you should do is save your audio in a wav file as that

```
        var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");

        using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
        {
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer((uint)stream.Size);
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(outputFile, buffer);
        }
```

After you're done with that you can transcode this one to mp3. For that I believe this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh452795
and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=242136
is the place to look into. ;)

Comment: On win32 we cannot write buffer to output file? I am getting `Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)`

Answer (score 0):

A complete example,

```
var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

    StorageFile sampleFile = await localfolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.wav", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");

    using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer((uint)stream.Size);
        await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(sampleFile, buffer);
    }
```